# Currency input in SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement the ability to change a currency value in an edit mode detailed view, but I am struggling to get formatted input for numeric values working.

```
struct JobDetailView_Edit: View {

@State var jobDetails: JobDetails

var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let f = NumberFormatter()
    f.numberStyle = .currency
    return f
}()

var body: some View {
    Form {

                Section(header: Text("General")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Job Name")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField($jobDetails.jobName)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }

                    TextField($jobDetails.hourlyRateBasic, formatter: currencyFormatter)

                }
... other unimportant code...
```

The data is passed in correctly, and the textfield displays the formatted value which is stored in $jobDetails.hourlyRateBasic, however, I cannot edit the field as I would be able to if it were a string. If I try to edit the field then press enter in the simulator, I get the following error message:

```
[SwiftUI] Failure setting binding's value. The supplied formatter does not produce values of type Double. This may be resolved by ensuring the binding and the output of the formatter are of the same type.
```

FYI $jobDetails.hourlyRateBasic is of type double.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a component that wraps around a UITextfield.

You can check it out here https://github.com/youjinp/SwiftUIKit

Here's the demo

[image: currency text field demo]

Comment: Got pure Swift (UIKit) version of this working. Thank you, @youjin

Comment: Awesome - Thanks @youjin. Qq. How do I initialise it with a value that's not nil?

Comment: @LateNate initialising with a value is now fixed in the latest commit.

Comment: this is great but needs to work in decimal to handle large financial numbers or currencies that have large values eg. yen, Indonesian rupiah etc.

Answer (score 3):

Ben Scheirman created a Tip Calculator that used a TextField with a currency formatter. The difference between his code and yours is that he stored the currency value in a Double?. NumberFormatter returns a NSNumber?.

You can see his code at https://github.com/nsscreencast/397-swiftui-tip-calculator

Comment: Updating to Beta 5 seems to have changed the way that the TextField works, I have fixed the issue with changing Double to Double? (this morning before updating it worked. However I know have an error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'TextField<_>' with an argument list of type '(String, text: Binding<Double?>, formatter: NumberFormatter)' ` when my TextField call is `TextField("", text: $basePay, formatter: currencyFormatter)`.
Appreciate the answer.

Comment: The documentation and Ben say that the initialiser is TextField("placeholder", value: $basePay, formatter: currencyFormatter)

Comment: Thank you kindly, oversight on my behalf.

Comment: This was getting as well. I haven't ever coded in Swift or SwiftUI and the language just feels clunky and poorly documented. Thanks for helping out with this!

Comment: You can always provide a binding to your Decimal like this: `TextField("Amount", value: Binding<NSNumber>(get: { decimalValue as NSDecimalNumber }, set: { decimalValue = $0.decimalValue }), formatter: currencyFormatter)`